# Include deployment timestamp into JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, deployment, wildfly

I'm writing web applications with Java EE 7 using JSP and servlets, deploying to a local Wildfly 10 server.

To help me developing and testing my code, it would be useful to include a little timestamp into the displayed webpage, so that I can directly see when the version I'm looking at in my browser was deployed.

That would prevent me from both forgetting to deploy changes as well as from looking at old cached versions instead of the latest one.

How can I display the date and time when a Java EE web app got deployed to my Wildfly server directly on the webpage?

My IDE is Eclipse Neon for Java EE, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not deploytime, but starttime of the application. Maybe it is useful for your purpose. You can inject the class and use it to display data on your page.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Deploytime
{
  private LocalDateTime starttime;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    starttime = LocalDateTime.now();
  }
}
```

Apart from that I can only think of [Maven Git Plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) which can generate things like buildtime, commit id, ... into a propery file, which you can also use to display it on the page (if you use git/maven).

Comment: Thanks, that might be indeed equally helpful. Going to test it tomorrow morning

Answer (score 1):

There is likely an API to do this too but you can get the server start time from the command line.  Assuming that you have your admin user name and password set up (i.e. you've run something like add-user.sh) you could run:

```
curl --digest "http://user:password@localhost:9990/management/core-service/platform-mbean/type/runtime?operation=attribute&name=start-time"
```

Of course, this is not Java - you'd either have to do a System.exec on this or use something like HttpClient.  Additionally, the big issue here is that you've got to have your admin username and password available to the code.

The [Wildfly HTTP Management Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API) go into some more detail with a small sample Java snippet.

**EDIT**:
Sorry - should not have assumed that the server restarts on deployment.  You can get deployment time for a web app with:

```
curl --digest "http://user:password@localhost:9990/management/deployment/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/?operation=attribute&name=enabled-time"
```

However, that seems more difficult than the other answer of running something at startup.  I don't see a deployment time for a webapp as that time would have to be stored somewhere in case of server restarts.

Comment: Please note that don't restart the whole server to deploy a new version of my application, I just let it automatically publish the new build and then restart the module. Your approach only shows the server start time, not the module start time, right?